Access and modify attributes of svg markup elements
I have a simple lwc component whose markup and js is below. The template contains svg tags. I want to access and modify few elements
Like in this example i want to access the circle element and change its color to white.
I tried to grab the element by adding data-id attribute but it did not work
Markup
<template>
  <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="green" data-id="circle"></circle>
    <text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">SVG</text>
  </svg>
</template>

Javascript
connectedCallback () {
    this.template.querySelector('[data-id="circle"]').setAttribute('style', 'stroke:white;fill:white;')
  }


This is because in connectedCallback(), not all your HTML elements are loaded yet. You can use renderedCallback() to query your HTML elements.
Referring to the official documentation here. For connectedCallback(), the following quote was taken as is from the documentation:

You can’t access child elements from the callbacks because they don’t exist yet.

Code block from documentation:
<template>
  <div>Some content</div>
</template>

import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class ConnectedCallbackExample extends LightningElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    // This doesn't work
    const div = this.template.querySelector("div"); //this will not work, will return null.
  }
}

Hence, you can get the elements in renderedCallback(), as such:
renderedCallback () {
    this.template.querySelector('[data-id="circle"]').setAttribute('style', 'stroke:white;fill:white;')
}


Thanks it works for me
